# Running windows7 on ubuntu Virtual Box for games

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, virtualbox, games

I'm currently using ubuntu 15.10 32 bit,
I installed Virtualbox with

windows7 32 bit in it with

3.5GB ram and

256 shared vga

4 processors,

and Enabled 2d,

3d acceleration.

Installed Guest permissions under safe mode then Installed Direct X 11...

My current graphic card is nvidia Geforce GTX 750 OC..

Now.. My Problem..

When I go for dxdiag in cmd AGP Acceleration is not available...

I've tried everything I can possibly think of..

and yet I can not run any game whatsoever.

Comment: how is that problem related to Ubuntu? It looks like a windows problem. driver installed?

Comment: if you do the same thing on windows instead of ubuntu you won't encounter this problem..

Answer (score -1):

Look, i don't recomend you run a game under virtualbox (if the game is a low graphic before accelerations graphic , like starcraft 1, doom 1 and prince of percia, no problem, but with virtual box, is 99% chance of don't run (like warcraft 3).

Try "PlayOnLinux" , can a lot of games under wine ...

Comment: Check youtube.. there are high end games that can run under virtualbox very smoothly!

Comment: Only for old games, like starcraft 1 , doom 1.
In the most cases, use wine is the best choice.
I m not talk about isn t run, but isn't be better then wine